# Evaluate a matrix and vector multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in M_{3x3}(\mathbb{R})$ (a 3x3 matrix in the reals). Its characteristic polynomial is $-t^3+4t^2-6$. Supppose that there is a matrix C, where $C=-A^3+4A^2-6I$ where I is the identity matrix. Notice that the matrix C is exactly in the form of the characterisitic poynomial, but just made up of the matrix A. Let $B= (v_1, v_2, v_3)$ be a basis for $R^3$, and each vector in B is an eigenvector of A (So $v_1$ would be $\lambda_1$), and so on. Evaluate $Cv_i$, for every vector $v_1, v_2, v_3$

So how would I go about doing this? It seems like that C is like the characteristic polynomial, but just made up of the matrix A. I can't seem to connect the dots - I know for a fact that B is a basis, so every vector in it must be linearly independent. I just do not know how to put this all together. Can someone help me here?

Comment: Could you use the [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem)?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I'm afraid that I do not know it. Can Cramer's rule be used here? I know it's not applicable but it seems to have some similarity

Comment: Try taking an eigenvector of $A$ (with an assumed eigenvalue - what to you know about the eigenvalues of $a$?) - and applying $C$ to it using the expression you have been given and linearity. It is simpler than you think.

Comment: $Cv_i=(\lambda_jI-A)(\lambda_kI-A)(\lambda_iI-A)v_i$ where $\{i,j,k\}$ is a permutation of $\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: $Cv_1=(-A^3+4A^2-6I)v_1=(-A^3v_1+4A^2v_1-6v_1)=(-\lambda_1^3+4\lambda_1^2-6)v_1=...$

Answer (score 1):

Since $Av_i=\lambda_1v_i$ for $i\in\{1,2,3\}$,

we have $Cv_i=(-A^3+4A^2-6I)v_i=-A^3v_i+4A^2v_i-6v_i=(-\lambda_i^3+4\lambda_i^2-6)v_i=0 $

for $i\in\{1,2,3\}$.

Alternatively, if you knew the [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem), it would tell you that $C$ is the zero matrix.